# How to calculate tax for Precious Metal Sales in Ohio

Tags: united-states, taxes, precious-metals, ohio

So recently Ohio did away with tax on precious metal sales. I've been wanting to produce precious metal items for a while and decided I want to open an online store.

I'm trying to understand how to charge tax on items I sell. There's two types of items.

1. Pure silver jewelry made entirely by me from silver grain
2. 1 ounce bars and coins of pure silver

If the state of Ohio doesn't charge tax on precious metal sales, I think it applies to the bars and coins of pure silver. However, I'm not sure how to apply that to the pure silver jewelry I manufacture.

Do I need to charge tax on my labor to create the item?
What about premiums on the silver? There's not a zero cost for me to go from silver grain to a custom bar or coin. There's labor involved there as well.

Comment: I'd suggest getting with a CPA about the tax issues.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about personal finance. Find a local sales tax specialists to work with.